# Android App and Testing Not Working

Tags: android, testing, apk

[This is the message I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84SLI.png)

So I'm trying to test my game using the alpha testing feature in google play. I have waited over 24 hours and I was pleased to see it was published. However, my alpha testers including myself never received an email notifying us of its release. When I followed the link to see it in the store, the url gave me "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server". Someone please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: better to read this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?visit_id=1-636285035199732753-927958926&p=releases_read&rd=1

Comment: @EliasFazel Yeah I followed the steps on the developer console when I first released my alpha. Did you click on the image I have linked? It shows published and it's confusing me. Should I remove my first alpha and try a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your setup correctly, you haven't actually *released* the game. Rather, you've published it to your alpha channel - which is why Google Play says the app is published. (Once any channel has an APK released, the app is considered published)

Depending on how you've configured your alpha channel, only users who are in the alpha group will be able to see your build. You can see who's authorized to view your alpha group by looking at "Release Management" and finding your alpha channel.

Assuming that your email is in a group authorized to see the alpha channel, you may also have to opt in. If you go to "https://play.google.com/apps/testing/", what do you see? You may have to click a link on that page to become a tester.

Comment: I don't know what is was but when I followed that link I input the alpha link which I had originally used and it worked perfectly thank you so much!!!